# MongoDB: Copying an array to another array in the same document

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm currently working on an online jewelry store with MongoDB, and I need to copy the brands contained in the "brands" array into a new array called "brandsNetherlands".

```
{    
            "_id" : ObjectId("569d03b66abefa8be9c49f26"),
            "brands" : [
                    "Brand1"
                    "Brand2"
                    "Brand3"
            ],
            "name" : "Family Jewels",
            "address" : "",
            "housenr" : "",
            "postalcode" : "1234 AQ",
            "city" : "Amsterdam",
            "phone" : "+31 570 - 514200",
            "email" : "jewelry@email.nl",
            "web" : "http://www.familyjewels.nl/",
            "kind" : "horloges",
            "country" : "Nederland",
            "brandsNetherlands" : [ ]
}
```

This is an example of the current build-up of one of the documents contained in tbe "wholesalers" collection. I need a non-static script that will allow me to move or copy the brands listed in the "brands" array into the empty "brandsNetherlands" array. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate the data in the document?

Answer (score 0):

For relatively small data, you can achieve the above by iterating the collection using a **[`snapshot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/)** with the cursor's **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** method and updating each document as follows:

```
db.wholesalers.find({ 
    "brands": { "$exists": true, "$type": 4 } 
}).snapshot().forEach(function(doc){ 
    db.wholesalers.updateOne(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "brandsNetherlands": doc.brands } }
    );
});
```

---

Whilst this is optimal for small collections, performance with large collections is greatly reduced since looping through a large dataset and sending each update operation per request to the server incurs a computational penalty.

The **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** API comes to the rescue and greatly improves performance since write operations are sent to the server only once in bulk. Efficiency is achieved since the method does not send every write request to the server (as with the current update statement within the **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** loop) but just once in every 1000 requests, thus making updates more efficient and quicker than currently is.

Using the same concept above with the **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** loop to create the batches, we can update the collection in bulk as follows.

In this demonstration the **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** API available in MongoDB versions `>= 2.6 and < 3.2` uses the **[`initializeUnorderedBulkOp()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp)** method to execute in parallel, as well as in a nondeterministic order, the write operations in the batches:

var bulk = db.wholesalers.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0; // counter to keep track of the batch update size

```
db.wholesalers.find({ 
    "brands": { "$exists": true, "$type": 4 } 
}).snapshot().forEach(function(doc){ 

    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "brandsNetherlands": doc.brands } 
    });

    counter++; // increment counter
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(); // Execute per 1000 operations and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
        bulk = db.wholesalers.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});
```

---

The next example applies to the new MongoDB version `3.2` which has since deprecated the **[`Bulk()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** API and provided a newer set of apis using **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)**.

It uses the same cursors as above but creates the arrays with the bulk operations using the same **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)** cursor method to push each bulk write document to the array. Because write commands can accept no more than 1000 operations, there's need to group operations to have at most 1000 operations and re-intialise the array when the loop hits the 1000 iteration:

```
var cursor = db.wholesalers.find({
         "brands": { "$exists": true, "$type": 4 } 
    }),
    bulkUpdateOps = [];

cursor.snapshot().forEach(function(doc){ 
    bulkUpdateOps.push({ 
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": { "brandsNetherlands": doc.brands } }
         }
    });

    if (bulkUpdateOps.length === 1000) {
        db.wholesalers.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps);
        bulkUpdateOps = [];
    }
});         

if (bulkUpdateOps.length > 0) { db.wholesalers.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps); }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but nothing seems to happen when I try to execute any of these commands. Nothing happens when I make an external script file and run it in Mongo, and I don't get any notifications when I place it directly in the command prompt. I have a feeling that for some reason Mongo just completely refuses to execute it.

Comment: What's your MongoDB version?

Comment: My MongoDB version is 3.2.7.

Comment: Obviously the first statement that uses `db.wholesalers.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()` bulk update is out of the question. However, if you run the script which uses the `bulkWrite()` API in mongo shell then it should work, you should be able to see the [`WriteResult`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#properties) object that gives you the details of the bulk write operation in terms of the number of documents matched, updated etc. in the console. You should also check whether you are running the commands against the right collection (check names and db etc).

Comment: I've managed to make the query work by changing the $type from 4 to 2, but the entries are displayed in a very strange way. Whereas the brands are just flat strings like `"BrandOne", "BrandTwo", "BrandThree"`, the entries in brandNetherlands are shown as `{"1" "B" "2" "r" "3" "a" "4" "n" "5" "d" "6" "O" "7" "n" "8" "e"}, {"1" "B" "2" "r" "3" "a" "4" "n" "5" "d" "6" "T" "7" "w" "8" "o"}, {"1" "B" "2" "r" "3" "a" "4" "n" "5" "d" "6" "T" "7" "h" "8" "r" "9" "e" "10" "e"}`. Is there any way to turn these entries into strings, or re-enter these values as strings?